# Waze deeplink, what is the meaning of setting *both* Q & LL parameters?

Tags: waze

When launching Waze deeplink -
What is the meaning of setting **both Q & LL** parameters?

For example:
`https://waze.com/ul?q=66%20Acacia%20Avenue&ll=45.6906304,-120.810983&navigate=yes` vs.
`https://waze.com/ul?ll=45.6906304,-120.810983&navigate=yes` 
Documentation isn't clear about it and it looks like the same behavior:
https://developers.google.com/waze/deeplinks#combining-parameters